# How does the upgradable ownership of a mutex affect other threads?

Tags: c++, boost-thread

the situation is:

a thread acquires an upgradable ownership of a boost::shared_mutex and is calling unlock_upgrade_and_lock(), which blocks because the other threads are possessing shared ownership of the same shared_mutex at the moment.

Will upgradable ownership of the first thread prevent(block) other threads when they are trying to "lock_shared" the shared_mutex so that all those already sharing ownership will finally unlock_shared and exclusive ownership for the first thread be guaranteed?

Or there is a possibility for the first thread to stay blocked for as long as there is another thread sharing the mutex?

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming the Boost implementation vaguely models the WG21 proposal from Howard Hinnant ...)

Converting from shared ownership to upgrade ownership prevents any new threads acquiring the lock, so eventually all the shared owners will release it and the thread with upgrade ownership can convert it to exclusive ownership. This is the point of the "upgrade lock" as opposed to just shared and exclusive locks, see the explanation in [N3427](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3427.html#OverviewUpgrade):

> Note that an alternative design of try-converting from shared to exclusive, instead of from shared to upgrade as shown, would be susceptible to update (writer) starvation. This is because as long as there are multiple searchers (shared locks), none of the searchers can ever successfully try-convert to updaters. It is only by successfully registering yourself as the single thread having upgrade ownership and then blocking on a conversion from upgrade to exclusive, do you enable the implementation to start blocking new searchers from obtaining a shared lock so that you can eventually obtain the exclusive lock as existing searchers are cleared out.